# MSSQL Stored Procedure: Compare Parameter with Column if ISNUMERIC

Tags: sql-server, casting, compare, isnumeric

I have following table "Managers" (simplified):

```
ID, int
Name, nvarchar(100)
```

In a stored procedure that has one argument ("Search", type nvarchar), I want to select every row where

1. The ID-Column is exactly @Search **OR**
2. The Name-Column contains @Search.

At the moment, my select in the stored procedure looks something like this:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Managers WHERE
(ISNUMERIC(@Search) = 1 AND [ID] = CAST(@Search AS INT)) Or
Contains([Name], @Search)
```

If I call the stored procedure with @Search = 1321 (example), the select works.

But if I have a @Search - parameter that is not numeric (example "HES"), I get the following error:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'HES' to data type int.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Raphi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Managers
WHERE [ID] = CASE
               WHEN ISNUMERIC(@Search) = 1 AND @Search NOT LIKE '%.%' THEN CAST(@Search AS INT)
               ELSE -1
             END
OR Contains([Name], @Search)
```

Comment: Something does not work: if the parameter is a decimal value, "132.4", ISNUMERIC returns 1, but the CAST to INT fails.